# In my bash loop over a list of some servers the script exits after execution a perl script with ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a problem similiar to this one:

[in my bash loop over a list of some servers, if the ssh connects the bash script exits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214512/in-my-bash-loop-over-a-list-of-some-servers-if-the-ssh-connects-the-bash-script)

Unfortunately `ssh` is called from a perl script I can't edit (so I won't be able to add `-n` to `ssh` commad).

What else could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did:

```
my_script < /dev/null
```

and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

put a fake `ssh` in your path that delegates the call to the real ssh and adds `-n`